# Download a website's favicon.ico through Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've tried Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type : "GET",
  url : "http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://www.google.com",
  success : function(result) {
      // use the .ico result somewhere
  }
});
```

which gives me the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://www.google.com. No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin
'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So I tried to allow CORS on my Apache server, but found out the site I download from needs to have CORS allowed too. And if I understand this right I can't download anything from an external domain through javascript, images, text, whatnot?

I tried to go around this by calling a php script on my webserver through ajax instead:

```
var domain = "www.google.com";
$.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url : "php/fetchIcon.php",
   data : {
     'domainName' : domain
   },
   success : function(result) {
     // use the .ico result somewhere
   }
});
```

fetchIcon.php:

```
$domainName = false;
if(isset($_POST['domainName'])){
    $domainName = $_POST['domainName'];
}
echo file_get_contents("http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://".$domainName, true);
```

In the Ajax success result I get back the image's binary code, but it seems broken in some way.

1. If I want to display the .ico file, can I do something like:
   "document.getElementById("img").src = result;" ? In my project I want to use "THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(result);". But that's a bit too much for this question.
2. Do I need to use Base64 encoding/decoding and how?
3. Is there an easier way or hack to do it just in Javascript without PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems right that you get binary code. What else did you expect? Don't think you can do it with JS only.

Comment: I expected nothing else. I just want to know how I can use the file or display it

Comment: Does this work: `<img src="fetchIcon.php?domainName=www.google.com" />` (make sure to change `$_POST` to `$_GET`).  Let's keep it nice and simple.  AJAX isn't needed here.

Comment: THANKS a lot Rocket Hazmat. That was way easier than I thought. While here, why not POST?

Comment: @user2010496: Because you can't send a POST request with an `<img/>` tag.  The query string in the URL is GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, answered by Rocket Hazmat:

fetchIcon.php:

```
$domainName = false;
if(isset($_GET['domainName'])){
    $domainName = $_GET['domainName'];
}
echo file_get_contents("http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://".$domainName, true);
```

Simplest way to display that it worked without CORS restrictions:

```
      <img src="fetchIcon.php?domainName=www.google.com" />
```

Otherwise this would have been sufficient:

```
      <img src="http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://www.google.com"/>
```

or the way I wanted to load a new texture uniform in THREE.js, in javascript, which I kept outside the question, but maybe someone run into the same problem as me:

```
iconUniform.map.value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("fetchIcon.php?domainName=www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i think you are making it more complex it simple i tried the below code and it worked for me

```
        <img id='favicon' src='http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://www.google.com'/>
```

so why are you using ajax request even if you want to change the soruce of the image you can do it easily with javascript

```
   document.getElementById('favicon').src="address"; //address  can contain new source
```

Comment: The thing is, I needed the icon in javascript context, and then CORS became a problem. Which forced me into using php and letting the webserver be a proxy for the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean download as in *download to a file*, but this would do it in PHP. You could call this AJAX style if you need it to return the path to your JS function...

```
$url = 'http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://www.google.com';
$img = 'icons/favicon.ico';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```